# magento Lock wait timeout exceeded sales_flat_order_grid

Tags: sql, magento, timeout, locking

I have a magento site with few extensions. The main extension is giftcard extension for unique codes. We are running promotion right now with 800K codes so it is creating huge traffic. Problem is now it is creating ghost orders as after taking payment - on the last moment when order must be registered from reserved order to confirmed - it shows table lockout error.

Exact error is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `sales_flat_order_grid` (`entity_id`, `status`, `store_id`, `customer_id`, `base_grand_total`, `base_total_paid`, `grand_total`, `total_paid`, `increment_id`, `base_currency_code`, `order_currency_code`, `store_name`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `billing_name`, `shipping_name`) SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`status`, `main_table`.`store_id`, `main_table`.`customer_id`, `main_table`.`base_grand_total`, `main_table`.`base_total_paid`, `main_table`.`grand_total`, `main_table`.`total_paid`, `main_table`.`increment_id`, `main_table`.`base_currency_code`, `main_table`.`order_currency_code`, `main_table`.`store_name`, `main_table`.`created_at`, `main_table`.`updated_at`, CONCAT(IFNULL(table_billing_name.firstname, ''), ' ', IFNULL(table_billing_name.middlename, ''), ' ', IFNULL(table_billing_name.lastname, '')) AS `billing_name`, CONCAT(IFNULL(table_shipping_name.firstname, ''), ' ', IFNULL(table_shipping_name.middlename, ''), ' ', IFNULL(table_shipping_name.lastname, '')) AS `shipping_name` FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `table_billing_name` ON `main_table`.`billing_address_id`=`table_billing_name`.`entity_id` LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `table_shipping_name` ON `main_table`.`shipping_address_id`=`table_shipping_name`.`entity_id` WHERE (main_table.entity_id IN('140650')) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `status` = VALUES(`status`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `customer_id` = VALUES(`customer_id`), `base_grand_total` = VALUES(`base_grand_total`), `base_total_paid` = VALUES(`base_total_paid`), `grand_total` = VALUES(`grand_total`), `total_paid` = VALUES(`total_paid`), `increment_id` = VALUES(`increment_id`), `base_currency_code` = VALUES(`base_currency_code`), `order_currency_code` = VALUES(`order_currency_code`), `store_name` = VALUES(`store_name`), `created_at` = VALUES(`created_at`), `updated_at` = VALUES(`updated_at`), `billing_name` = VALUES(`billing_name`), `shipping_name` = VALUES(`shipping_name`)

There seems to have no reference except : 140650 for entity id for sales_flat_order_grid.

If any one have any idea please let me know the possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

This issue may be related to a bug in earlier versions of Magento.  It used to be that the INSERT into sales_flat_order_grid occurred within a transaction.  And because of the query that Magento uses to populate it the query planner could not figure out which rows to lock it locked the entire sales_flat_order_grid table. And because that happens within a transaction the lock is retained until COMMIT.

If this is what is causing your problem you will need to resolve the move the order grid calculation to commit_after.

Comment: How can I move code to commit_after?
I am unable to find the code where order is saving order data in grid.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am replying my own question - in case someone else find helpful.

Solution: run Insert query for missing `entity_id` from `sales_flat_order`, run above query by replacing `140650` with `main_table.entity_id NOT IN (select sales_flat_order.entity_id from sales_flat_order)` and that will solve it. This is because both tables share same `entity_id` values.

I also came to know please set slow queries log as you can see which query taking long ( they are the one creating deadlock as db server resources gets occupied there ) - soon as I find such and resolved the third party extension slow query problem - no error of table locks.